# List index out of range when moving

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code for the game of fifteen, excluding the 'won' function:

import sys

```
d = int(sys.argv[1])

dimension = (d * d) - 1

board = [[0 for x in range(d)] for y in range(d)]

def main():

    global d
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 or 0 > d or d > 9:
        print("usage: python fifteen.py size")
        exit()

def init():

    global d

    global dimension

    global board

    for row in range(d):
        for col in range(d):
            board[row][col] = dimension
            dimension -= 1
    if d % 2 == 0:
        board[d-1][d-3] = 1
        board[d-1][d-2] = 2

def draw():

    global d

    global dimension

    global board

    for row in range(d):
        for col in range(d):
            if board[row][col] == 0:
                print("__", end="")
            else:
                print("{:0=2d} ".format(board[row][col]), end="")
        print("")

def move():

    global d

    global dimension

    global board

    while True:
        tile = int(input("Tile to move: "))
        if tile > 0:
            break

    for row in range(d):
        for col in range(d):
            if board[row][col] == tile:
                colleft = col - 1
                colright = col + 1
                rowup = row - 1
                rowdown = row + 1

                if board[row][colleft] == 0 and colleft >= 0:
                    board[row][colleft] = tile
                    board[row][col] = 0
                    return True

                elif board[row][colright] == 0 and colright < d:
                    board[row][colright] = tile
                    board[row][col] = 0
                    return True

                elif board[rowup][col] == 0 and rowup >= 0:
                    board[rowup][col] = tile
                    board[row][col] = 0
                    return True

                elif board[rowdown][col] == 0 and rowdown < d:
                    board[rowdown][col] = tile
                    board[row][col] = 0
                    return True
                return False
    return True


main()

init()

draw()

move()

draw()
```

When I want to move 2 or 3 for instance, I keep getting "IndexError: list index out of range":

Erorr message:

python3 fifteen.py 3

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "fifteen.py", line 83, in <module>

    move()

File "fifteen.py", line 72, in move

    elif board[rowdown][col] == 0 and rowdown < d:
```

IndexError: list index out of range

What do I have to do to make this work properly?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example!

Comment: Add traceback and format the code properly.

Comment: I am sorry Amit, I am new here and just wanted to ask something but you are not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because rowdown and colright could be bigger than the max index of your board.

for example, d = 3.
when row = 2, rowdown = 3 which is out of index of board.

Comment: How can I change this?